# Updating profile via Metadata API from Apex gives weird error

Tags: metadata-api, permissions, profile

I am trying to automatically enable pages for profiles ([profileApexPageAccess doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#profileApexPageAccess_title)) via Metadata API. Here is my method:

```
public static void updateProfileAccesses(String profileName, List<String> pageNames) {

    if(!String.isBlank(profileName)) {
        MetadataService.IMetadataPort service = createService();
        MetadataService.IReadResult readResult =        
                service.readMetadata('Profile', new String[] { profileName });
        MetadataService.Metadata[] records = readResult.getRecords();

       MetadataService.Profile p = (MetadataService.Profile)records[0];

       for(String pageName : pageNames) {

            Boolean isPageEnabled = false;

            for(MetadataService.ProfileApexPageAccess pa : p.pageAccesses) {
                if(pa.apexPage == pageName) {
                    pa.enabled = true;
                    isPageEnabled = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!isPageEnabled) {
                System.debug('page is NOT in the list'); // this message never appears in the logs
                MetadataService.ProfileApexPageAccess pap = new MetadataService.ProfileApexPageAccess();
                pap.apexPage = pageName;
                pap.enabled = true;
                p.pageAccesses.add(pap);
            }
       }

       MetadataService.SaveResult[] sr = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] {p});
       if(sr!=null) {
            System.debug('sr error ' + sr[0].errors);
       }           
   }
}
```

SaveResult always has an error with the following details:

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
>
> You can't edit tab settings for AddOnDefinition, as it's not a valid
>   tab.

I haven't found any info on AddOnDefinition and what it has to do with ProfileApexPageAccess. Does anyone know what that might mean?

UPD I've tried the same code in another dev org and got

> You can't edit tab settings for Calibration, as it's not a valid tab.

[Calibration](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=calibration_overview.htm)

AND I found AddOnDefinition in ProfileTabVisibility list ([tabVisibilities doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#profiletabvisibility_title)) but I still don't know how to get pass this error because I am not changing tabVisibilities at all.

**Has anyone successfully updated page accesses automatically via Apex?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The profile that you are retrieving and then updating has many fields:

```
public class Profile extends Metadata {
    public String type = 'Profile';
    public String fullName;
    public MetadataService.ProfileApplicationVisibility[] applicationVisibilities;
    public MetadataService.ProfileApexClassAccess[] classAccesses;
    public Boolean custom;
    public MetadataService.ProfileCustomPermissions[] customPermissions;
    public String description;
    public MetadataService.ProfileExternalDataSourceAccess[] externalDataSourceAccesses;
    public MetadataService.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity[] fieldPermissions;
    public MetadataService.ProfileLayoutAssignment[] layoutAssignments;
    public MetadataService.ProfileLoginHours loginHours;
    public MetadataService.ProfileLoginIpRange[] loginIpRanges;
    public MetadataService.ProfileObjectPermissions[] objectPermissions;
    public MetadataService.ProfileApexPageAccess[] pageAccesses;
    public MetadataService.ProfileRecordTypeVisibility[] recordTypeVisibilities;
    public MetadataService.ProfileTabVisibility[] tabVisibilities;
    public String userLicense;
    public MetadataService.ProfileUserPermission[] userPermissions;
    ...
}
```

and it sounds like the error is caused by something other than the `pageAccesses` data that you are trying to update. (Why tabs that don't exist or can't be updated get included when you query the profile is an open question.)

I suggest you try and work around the problem by clearing some of the other fields than `pageAccesses` starting with the one that includes "tab" in its name:

```
MetadataService.Profile p = (MetadataService.Profile)records[0];
p.tabVisibilities = new MetadataService.ProfileTabVisibility[] {};
```

and see if that eliminates the error.

Or instead of querying, you could "new" the `Profile` and just set its `fullName` and `pageAccesses` fields.

Comment: Hi Keith! Thanks HEAPS for your answer. Both of your suggestions do work without resetting tab visibilities. Do you know why they are not being reset? (i.e. can I expect that production users tab visibilities won't be spoiled this way?)

Comment: @bananka In my experience metadata operations don't remove things by default. I can't absolutely guarantee that everything will be fine in production but if it works in a sandbox or a dev org it should work the same in production.

Comment: @KeithC It works! Thanks mate.